# Отступ вверху страницы

Tags: css, html5

Только начал изучение верстки и не могу найти ответ. В стилях обнулил отступы margin и padding для тега body, но сверху страницы остался отступ. Для наглядности покрасил body в красный цвет. Откуда он берется? Отступ исчезает если в header написать padding: 1px;

```css
body {
 font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: red;
}

header {
 background-color: #f6f2f1;
 height: 770px;
    /*padding: 1px;*/
}

.container {
 width: 1250px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
 height: 90px;
 background-color: #312f30;
}

li {
 display: inline;
}

li a {
 color: #e0e0e0;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <title>Первая верстка</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:\Верстка\css\style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
 <section>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
 </section>
 <footer>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Используйте веб инспектор браузера для отлова таких ситуаций. В данном случае это отступы ul в меню.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываем **DevTools** ("*Просмотр кода страницы*" или ctrl+shift+i), с начала и до конца просматриваем элементы, и находим `ul`, у которого `margin-top: 16px` - это и есть наш отступ.

http://joxi.ru/xAebeMqtYzO78r[image: введите сюда описание изображения]